# Can not allowed a return type

Tags: visual-c++

```
//Header file
ref class CControl {
    CControl(); 
};

//cpp file
CControl::Ccontrol() {

}
```

I am getting the error.

```
C2533::constructer not allowed a return type
```

Comment: What type would you want to return?

Comment: Is this your real code copy/pasted as-is? This code as shown should not compile. You have a name mismatch between `CControl()` in the header file and `Ccontrol()` in the cpp file. There is no return type shown in this code (it is probably a side effect of the mismatch).